# custom ping command c++ mingw

Tags: c++, sockets, mingw, ping

**What i want to do:**

Make a simple ICMP ping function in c++ mingw to check if the machines on my network respond and are online. Returns true or false.

**What i tried:**

I was successful in making quite an advanced ping function and class using SFML network module. It works fine but unfortunately *needs* a port to connect. And some of the machines on the network dont have any ports open or all have different ports open. ICMP ping would be the best to counter this i think as it doesnt need the port.

I looked online for solutions and found a lot of forums talking about sockets and such, but none of them (due to differences between mingw and gcc) work for mingw (it apparenty lacks the libs or something). That being said i tried making my own socket library but that also failed due to the same lib missing reasons. I wasnt even able to start.

**Conclusion:**

So in the end im left back at square one not knowing where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out libping at https://download.joedog.org/libping/

Comment: or the implementation of the ping command at https://github.com/sryze/ping

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. I was Successfully able to add it to my project. I'm also developing a library for sockets / ping in a new fashion compatible with object oriented network programming in cpp. This will help a lot